# Why does my Python script return an object as a string

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm writing a small python script to combine two excel files into one. It's fairly simple, but I'm getting an error inside the `updateExcelFile()` method stating the 'str' object has no attribute 'DACNum.' This error occurs on row 71 of the excel file, the first blank row. Could someone point out why this is? Thanks!

> Here's the full traceback:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\jasonmcclafferty\Desktop\Python\example.py", line 130, in 
> <module>
>     DACMgr.updateExcelFile(x, row)
>   File "C:\Users\jasonmcclafferty\Desktop\Python\example.py", line 109, 
> in updateExcelFile
>     DACMgr.workbook.active.cell(row=c_row, column=1, 
> value=DACReport.DACNum)
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'DACNum'
> [Finished in 3.3s with exit code 1]
> ```

```
import openpyxl
import os


print("Current directory: " + os.getcwd())
print()

class DACReport:
    DACNum = ''
    PlanNum = ''
    CNNum = ''
    FSCNum = ''
    Name = ''
    AppDetails = ''
    Agent = ''
    DevAddress = ''
    DateRec = ''
    Deadline = ''
    Decision = '' 
    FIReq = ''
    Fee = ''

    def __init__(self, DACNum, Name):
        self.DACNum = DACNum
        self.Name = Name

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Application #: ' + self.DACNum + ' Applicant Name: ' + self.Name


class DACReader:

    workbook = ''

    def __init__(self, workbook):
        self.workbook = workbook

    ## Reads the record at the given row, creates a DACEntry object from it and prints the string representation.
    def get_record_ar(self, c_row):
        w_bk = self.workbook
        w_sht = w_bk.active


        c_DAC = w_sht.cell(row=c_row, column=1).value
        c_Name = w_sht.cell(row=c_row, column=2).value

        issues = []

        if (c_DAC != None):
            if (c_Name == None):
                issues.append(DACReport(c_DAC, c_Name))

            else:
                tmp = DACReport(c_DAC, c_Name)
        else:
            return 0

        ## Object is printed and returned here, should also be written to excel

        if tmp != None:
            DACMgr.updateDACList(tmp)

            return tmp

    ## Reads the record at the given row, creates a DACRecord object from it and prints the string representation.
    def get_record_old(self, c_row):
        w_bk = self.workbook
        w_sht = w_bk.active
        tmp = ''

        c_DAC = w_sht.cell(row=c_row, column=5).value
        c_Name = w_sht.cell(row=c_row, column=6).value

        issues = []

        if (c_DAC != None):
            if (c_Name == None):
                issues.append(DACReport(c_DAC, c_Name))

            else:
                tmp = DACReport(c_DAC, c_Name)
        else:
            return 0

        ## Object is printed and returned here, should also be written to excel
        if tmp != None:
            DACMgr.updateDACList(tmp)

            return tmp


class DACMgr:

    DAClist = []

    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("daccomplete.xlsx")

    def __init__(self, DAClist):
        self.DAClist = DAClist

    def updateDACList(DACReport):
        #print(DACReport)
        DACMgr.DAClist.append(DACReport)
        return 0

    # Updates the excel file with a DACReport at row = c_row
    def updateExcelFile(DACReport: DACReport, c_row: int):
            print(DACReport)
            DACMgr.workbook.active.cell(row=c_row, column=1, value=DACReport.DACNum)
            DACMgr.workbook.active.cell(row=c_row, column=2, value=DACReport.Name)

            openpyxl.writer.excel.save_workbook(DACMgr.workbook, "daccomplete.xlsx")    




aReader = DACReader(openpyxl.load_workbook('ardalsdacregister.xlsx'))
oReader = DACReader(openpyxl.load_workbook('olddacregister.xlsx'))


for x in range(3, 360,1):
    oReader.get_record_old(x)

for x in range(8,150,1):
    aReader.get_record_ar(x)

row = 1
for x in DACMgr.DAClist:
    print(x)
    DACMgr.updateExcelFile(x, row)
    row+=1
```

`

Comment: You need to show the full traceback. It would also be better to cut down your code to the minimum that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What method/line is the last one to call `updateExcelFile`?  I see a call to it at the end of your code, but I don't see how `DACMgr.DAClist` is populated, in order for its elements to be used as params to `updateExcelFile`

Comment: @jcfollower    Thanks for the reply! The only call to `updateExcelFile` is in the loop at the bottom of the code. `DACList` is populated inside the `get` methods. It's messy atm, I'm just trying to get something working before I optimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code at the end sends the elements of `DAClist` to `updateExcelFile`

```
for x in DACMgr.DAClist:
    print(x)
    DACMgr.updateExcelFile(x, row)
    row+=1
```

Meanwhile, `updateExcelFile` expects that input to be objects with certain attributes ... `value=DACReport.DACNum`.

It looks like when `DAClist` is being populated, a string is included in some cases rather than an object with the right attributes.

Your `get*` methods include this line ...

```
DACMgr.updateDACList(tmp)
```

Higher up, you set a default value ... `tmp = ''`.

You should probably either make the default value of `tmp` a `DACReport` object or in `updateExcelFile` you should check whether you're dealing with a DACReport before you try to access one of its attributes.

Comment: Solved! I put a flag in to only update the cell if tmp is an object of type DAC. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove self from the function and try...

```
def updateExcelFile(DACReport: DACReport, c_row: int):
        print(DACReport)
        DACMgr.workbook.active.cell(row=c_row, column=1, value=DACReport.DACNum)
        DACMgr.workbook.active.cell(row=c_row, column=2, value=DACReport.Name)

        openpyxl.writer.excel.save_workbook(DACMgr.workbook, "daccomplete.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I put the '.self' in to try to fix it and forgot to take it out, will do now. Any other ideas?

Comment: This works with the excel files I used. Can you please try and print that string. Maybe that will give some idea.

Comment: It prints the __str__() of the DACReport fine for the full list easily. The problem arises when it tries to print a blank row.